# Deactivate glossy ray visibility setting from python script for the scene

Tags: python, rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, reflection

I need to render a model, and for that, I need to deactivate the ray visibility options (glossy). I need to do it from the python script ( I need to activate it for one scene and deactivate it for another). How can I do it?

edit:
I tried out `bpy.context.object.cycles_visibility.glossy = False`, but it does not work, and the option in blender is still checked after I save my model.

Comment: To turn it off, I think it's `bpy.context.object.cycles_visibility.glossy = False` (Back on would naturally be `True`)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I have been doing it, but it has no effect. I just added this line:
`bpy.context.object.cycles_visibility.glossy = False` right before I render, but it has no effect, and the glossy option is checked in the blender application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply adding this line right before the rendering line worked for me:
`bpy.context.scene.world.cycles_visibility.glossy = False`.
I simply copied this code from the "info" window under scripting. After I unchecked the box, it shows the python code for this command.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial and thoroughly explain the solution and required workflow. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and why it works feel free to restore it, otherwise it may be deleted or converted into a comment. Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating the workflow and final results. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)